# Linha e coluna javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso de um script puro ou com jquery que execute uma estrutura de linha e coluna. Exemplo, se o usuario digitar 7 tenho que imprimir a seguinte estrutura:

```
x
xx
xxx
xxxx
xxxxx
xxxxxx
xxxxxxx
```

Tentei utilizar for porém só executa a linha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem várias formas de fazer isso. Quando você diz imprimir, vou usar o console para mostrar o resultado.

```
var numero = 7; // Número inserido pelo usuário.
var caracter = 'x'; // Caracter que deseja imprimir.
var resultado = ''; // Variável para armazenar o resultado e imprimir.

for(i = 0; i < numero; i++){
    resultado = resultado + caracter;
    console.log(resultado);
}
```

Isso irá resultar no console:

```
x
xx
xxx
xxxx
xxxxx
xxxxxx
xxxxxxx
```

Comment: Perfeito, muito obrigado!

Comment: De nada, disponha!